# Fill the form, click button, and show an alert every 5 minutes in online website

Tags: jquery, web

I want to refresh e-commerce page in every 5 minutes automatically. But itsn't only refresh the page, I need to fill *search box* first, and then click the *search button*, after that sort the result by clicking *sort button*, and last show an alert if the top result price less than $1000.
This is just my imagination. If this possible, how do I can do this?

Thankyou

Comment: So, did you try something. SO is not for asking possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function which fulfills all your requirements and call the function in a setInterval() and set the time for 5 minutes. 
Ex -

```
// Function for Setting Search Text 
function SearchAndClick(){
    $('#IDofSearchBox').val('SearchText');
    $('#IDofSearchBox').click();
    setTimeOut(ClickSortAndAlert(),10000);  //Wait for 10 seconds for the Search Results

}
// Function for clicking Sort and check the top result 
function ClickSortAndAlert(){
    $('#IDofSortButton').click();
    if($('TopInput').val()<1000){
        alert('hurray we have find an item for less then $1000');
    }
}
// Call at interval of 5 minutes
setInterval(SearchAndClick(),300000);
```

Hope this Idea Helps you . Please Inform if it worked